# Flask database tables can't find each other

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following code for SQLAlchemy based Flask database:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()

#Class for keeping track of users
class User(db.Model):
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable = False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable = False)
    messages = db.relationship('Message', backref = 'user', lazy = 'dynamic')
    chatrooms = db.relationship('ChatRoom', backref = 'user', lazy = 'dynamic')

    def __init__(self, name, pw):
        self.username = name
        self.password = pw

#Class for keeping track of chatrooms
class ChatRoom(db.Model):
    chat_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    creator_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.user_id'), nullable=False)
    title= db.Column(db.String(100), nullable = False)
    high_msg_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
    messages = db.relationship('Message', backref ='chat', lazy='dynamic')

    def __init__(self, title, creator_id):
        self.title = title
        self.creator_id = creator_id
        self.high_msg_id = 0

    #Add a message to the chatroom
    def add(message):
        high_msg_id = high_msg_id + 1
        message.chat_thread_id = high_msg_id

#Class for keeping track of messages
class Message(db.Model):
    msg_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    text = db.Column(db.String(1000), nullable = False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.user_id'), nullable=False)
    chat_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('chat.chat_id'), nullable=False)
    chat_thread_id = db.Column(db.Integer)

    def __init__(self, txt, chat_id):
        self.text = txt
        self.chat_id = chat_id
```

but I am getting the following error whenever I initialize it: Foreign key associated with column 'messages.chat_id' could not find table 'chat' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'chat_id'.
I find this incredibly strange since I don't get this error for any other relationship in this database, and I have no idea what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ChatRoom` model generates a table named `chatroom` and not `chat`. Hence, you need to either rename the foreign key to `chatroom.chat_id` or rename the generated table like so:

```
class ChatRoom(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'chat'
    # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You're putting your relationships on the wrong classes.

```
class User(db.Model):
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    ...

class ChatRoom(db.Model):
    chat_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    creator_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.user_id'), nullable=False)
    creator = db.relationship('User', backref='chatrooms_created')

class Message(db.Model):
    msg_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.user_id'), nullable=False)
    chat_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('chat.chat_id'), nullable=False)

    user = db.relationship('User', backref='messages')
    chat_room = db.relationship('ChatRoom', backref='messages')
```

See the [SQLAlchemy Documentation on relationships](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationships.html).

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but shouldn't you have the property ```__tablename__``` somewhere in your class definitions to reference them when using ```backref```?